# codeigniter CI-Smarty + Internationalization (i18n) for CodeIgniter 2.x

Tags: codeigniter, internationalization, smarty, multilingual

I'm developing a Codeigniter application that requires internationalization (i18n) support.

I'm using [CI-Smarty](https://github.com/Vheissu/Ci-Smarty) (Smarty 3) as a template solution, and [Internationalization (i18n) for CodeIgniter 2.x](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/CodeIgniter-2.1-internationalization-i18n), but I cant get the multilingual support to work with CI Smarty, I've tried to change the code, tried adding routes, and doing both at the same time but without success.

My site controller:

```
public function index() {
    $this->news();
} #index

public function news() {
    $xml = $this->pages->news();
    $data['news'] = $xml->xpath('//item');
    $data['date'] = $xml->xpath('//item/pubDate');
    $data['alphabet'] = $this->pages->alphabet();
    $data['numbers'] = $this->pages->numbers();
    $data['pagetitle'] = $this->config->item('news_pagetitle');
    $data['description'] = $this->config->item('news_description');
    $data['keywords'] = $this->config->item('news_keywords');
    $this->pages->page('news', $data);
} #news
```

My pages model:

```
function page($page, $data = NULL) {
    $data['base'] = base_url();
    $data['current'] = current_url();
    $data['page'] = $page;
    $data['title'] = $this->config->item('title');
    $data['tagline'] = $this->config->item('tagline');
    $data['datetime'] = date('l, F d, Y');
    $data['dateshow'] = date('Y-n-j');
    $this->parser->parse('header', $data);
    $this->parser->parse($page, $data);
    $this->parser->parse('footer', $data);
} #page
```

My routes.php:

```
$route['^(en|pt)/(.+)$'] = "$2";
// '/en', '/de', '/fr' and '/nl' URIs -> use default controller
$route['^(en|pt)$'] = $route['default_controller'];

// Prettify the url
$route['default_controller'] = 'site';
$route['404_override'] = 'site/e404';
$route['scaffolding_trigger']= "";

$route['(:any)'] = 'site/$1';
$route['guide/(:num)'] = 'guide/$1';
$route['shows/(:any)'] = 'shows/$1';
$route['shows/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'shows/$1/cat/$2';
$route['title/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'title/$1';
```

When I request the index page using the www.example.com/en/ which will show the news info it loads fine, but if I request the page news using www.example.com/en/news it does not load the news, and instead loads the 404 page, and do the same to all other pages.

The application works fine without the internationalization (i18n) support, loading all the pages ok, including the news page.

And also the internationalization (i18n) support works fine, I've tested it in a version without the CI-Smarty.

I need to translate this app into multiple languages, so I need to find a way for Codeigniter with CI-Smarty to support it. Is there one? Thanks to all those how can help.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with your routing and not your controller or model.

Comment: @DarkAshelin my routing (I assume you are talking about routes.php) is this way:

**I updated the question**

Comment: Well it seems that your routes point any url that starts with `en/` to the same controller: `default_controller`